# MySQL Stored Procedure, error: Result consisted of more than one row

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, procedure

I'm trying to write a MySQL Stored Procedure, but I'm having some issues.
When I try to execute it, I got error 1172: Result consisted of more than one row.
I don't have any idea what I'm doing wrong.

Here's my code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE bepaal_lijst_van_bij_te_bestellen_artikelen()
BEGIN
DECLARE varArtikel, varBesteld, varVoorraad, cnt, varVerschil, resultaten INT DEFAULT 0;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS __besteld_voorraad;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE __besteld_voorraad
    (artikelid INT, besteld INT, voorraad INT, controle INT) ENGINE = HEAP;

main: BEGIN
    -- test if table is empty
    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM items INTO cnt;
    IF cnt=0 THEN LEAVE main; END IF;

    SELECT items.artikel_id AS artikelid, items.aantal AS besteld, artikelen.voorraad AS voorraad
    FROM items 
    INNER JOIN artikelen 
    ON items.artikel_id=artikelen.artikel_id
    INTO varArtikel, varBesteld, varVoorraad;

    INSERT INTO __besteld_voorraad (artikelid,besteld,voorraad,controle)
    VALUES (varArtikel,varBesteld,varVoorraad,varVerschil);

    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM __besteld_voorraad INTO resultaten;
    SET cnt=1;

    -- loop
    lus: WHILE cnt<resultaten DO
        SELECT artikelid,besteld,voorraad FROM __besteld_voorraad 
        LIMIT cnt,resultaten
        INTO varArtikel, varBesteld, varVoorraad;

        IF (varVoorraad - varBesteld <= 0) THEN
            SET varVerschil = -1;
        ELSE
            SET varVerschil = 1;
        END IF;

        UPDATE __besteld_voorraad
        SET controle = varVerschil
        WHERE artikelid = varArtikel AND besteld = varBesteld AND voorraad = varVoorraad;

        SET cnt = cnt + 1;
    END WHILE lus;
END main;

SELECT artikelid, controle FROM __besteld_voorraad ORDER BY artikel_id ASC;
DROP TABLE __besteld_voorraad;
END
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its because your select into command returns more than one row. I don't understand the full concept but i guess you are trying to decrease the quantity once its sold?

**change this part**

```
SELECT items.artikel_id AS artikelid, items.aantal AS besteld, artikelen.voorraad AS voorraad
    FROM items 
    INNER JOIN artikelen 
    ON items.artikel_id=artikelen.artikel_id
    INTO varArtikel, varBesteld, varVoorraad;

    INSERT INTO __besteld_voorraad (artikelid,besteld,voorraad,controle)
    VALUES (varArtikel,varBesteld,varVoorraad,varVerschil);
```

**to:**

```
INSERT INTO __besteld_voorraad (artikelid,besteld,voorraad,controle)
    (SELECT
        items.artikel_id AS artikelid,
        items.aantal AS besteld,
        artikelen.voorraad AS voorraad
    FROM items INNER JOIN artikelen ON items.artikel_id=artikelen.artikel_id);
```

**and this part:**

```
SELECT artikelid,besteld,voorraad FROM __besteld_voorraad 
        LIMIT cnt,resultaten
```

**to:**

```
SELECT artikelid,besteld,voorraad FROM __besteld_voorraad 
        LIMIT cnt,1
```

I'm sure there could be a more elegant solution but as i said i can't understand your concept. Above correction is just to get rid of "Result consisted of more than one row" Error. give it a try!

Comment: Thanks, but now I'm getting 'a column doesn't match value count at row 1'-error.
What I'm trying to see is if stock minus orders is less than or equal to zero. (voorraad - besteld <= 0)